# how to force a link to be opened in a new tab using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want to make sure that in all tab enabled browsers, when a user clicks a link, it opens in a new tab. All i have got so far is the target keyword in the anchor, but is there some new html attribute that supports that function?

Comment: And `target="_blank"` is not working for you?

Comment: mm good question, but I don't think there is a solution for your question. In some browsers target="_blank" opens a new window I guess

Comment: I think that also depends upon your browser setting. In FF you can whether to open page in new tab or window. Same settings must be available in other browser. But unfortunate thing is that they are not manageable in javascript.

Comment: @Chinmayee Well, depending on your point of view here. As a user, I'm *very* glad that the browser, not the website, has ultimate say over matters such as this

Comment: @Yi Ya as a user, I do agree with you.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Completely agree. But it would be nice to have a standard way to suggest a hint to the browser (e.g., `target="_blanktab"`), which could then be handled via further options in the user's settings (with reasonable defaults, since most non-technical users don't change this stuff) -- giving the user *complete* control. :-)

Comment: @Nauman: Only one of your other five questions has received an acceptable answer? Really?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guaranteed way for that because you can change window opening behavior and tabbing options from within browser options.

The best you can do is to write your code using either `target="_blank"` or `window.open()`.

Comment: Did you mean "the best you can do"? :-)

Comment: @MaxVT, @T.J. Crowder: Oh I said the opposite. Corrected, thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a CSS3-property [target-new](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/WD-css3-hyperlinks-20040224/#target-new)

Unfortunately it isn't supported yet by any browser(I don't know any). But maybe you could already implement it for future use.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is `<a href="..." target="_blank"></a>`.

There is no standardized semantic way of telling the browser to open a new tab. This is because not all browsers have tabs. Take most mobile browsers, for example, they don't have tabs.

There is also no vendor specific way of doing this that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no HTML attribute that tells tab-enabled browsers to do this if they can, you're stuck with `target` using either "_blank" for new window or a specific name if you want to reuse a window. It would sure be nice, but there's not even anything in the current HTML5 working draft, at least not under [`a`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) or [`target`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#attr-hyperlink-target) (e.g., there's no ["context name"](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#valid-browsing-context-name-or-keyword) for "new tab").

**Edit**: But [look at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244026/how-to-force-a-link-to-be-opened-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript/4244116#4244116) (and vote up) [Dr.Molle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244026/how-to-force-a-link-to-be-opened-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript/4244116#4244116). CSS to the rescue (someday)!